# Does Maven update dependencies only during the development stage?

Tags: maven

Noob question. I'm considering to learn Maven. I understand what it does in general. Let's say I have a Maven Eclipse project. Then I create an executable JAR, and wrap it with launch4j.

Now I have `TestProgram.exe` file. Will Maven reload the dependencies, whenever there is a there is a new version available? Will the inner structure of the `TestProgram.exe` change over time as new versions of dependencies are loaded? Or does Maven update dependencies only during the development stage?

Comment: I think if you really want this feature, you can do this as you like. Who use your program need not only the program, but JDK, local repository, maven with version as in you environment and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a build tool. One of it's key benefits is that it yields a repeatable build process. It does not become part of your application.

The artefacts that are included in your build are fixed by the dependency versions that you specify in your project object model (aka pom.xml file).

If you need a newer version of one of these dependencies then you must update your pom.xml file and release a new version of your product.